# Navbar opacity on scroll vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js

I want to change the opacity of my fixed navbar background when user scrolling the page. Initially navbar background should be transparent and when scrolling down it background needs to be change to white.
Like this example https://codepen.io/michaeldoyle/pen/Bhsif

I have found various examples for this scenario using jquery. But I need to achieve this using vuejs.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('nav').addClass('transparent');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('transparent');
  }
});
```

I tried above code inside my vue page. I put it inside mounted(). But it doesn't work. I need to done this using vue. Not like above jquery.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <ul class="nav menu">
<li>
  <router-link to="/about" @click.native="closeNavBarFromChild">About</router-link>
</li>
<li class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
  <router-link to="/product" @click.native="closeNavBarFromChild">Product</router-link>
</li>
</ul>
    </nav>
```

This is how my navbar component looks like.

```
nav.navbar{
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
   transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

nav.navbar.transparent {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

this is the css part that i used.

Comment: `But it doesn't work` - in what way? errors in the console? what doesn't work about it?

Comment: nothing appears in console. I just use http://jsfiddle.net/m7yww8oa/157/ this simple example for testing. nothing happens. I put that jquery code inside mounted(). Is that right?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using vuejs

Answer (score 1):

Set your listener in `created` lifecycle hook:

```
export default {
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    onScroll (event) {
      // add/remove class
    }
  }
}
```